# 'IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`)' ...?

Tags: python, numpy, index-error

There are many questions with this error, but I have not been able to find where is the source of the problem in my code. The code I have is the following:

```
for i in segs:
    if relDiff(segs[i+1], segs[i]) > 0.05:
        arr_x[i] = 0; arr_y[i] = 0
```

I get the error on line three: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

`segs` is an array, and `relDiff` is a function I made that calculates the relative difference. Here is that function:

```
def relDiff(x,x_ref):
    return np.abs((x-x_ref)/x_ref)
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you take time to look at `i`within the loop?  Does it make sense to index a `segs` with an element of itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using items from `segs` as indexes of `arr_x` and `arr_y`, `segs` has to be a list/array of integers. Otherwise, you'd have to convert each item to an integer, like `arr_x[int(i)]`. Whether or not that would logically make sense to do that in you program is up to you to determine, since your requirements are unknown. We don't know what `segs` contains.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in segs:
    print(i)
    segs[i]
```

The problem should become obvious!

```
In [317]: x = np.array([1.2, 3.2, .5])
In [318]: for i in x:
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     x[i]
     ...: 
1.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-318-41c2ba7b6f7d>", line 3, in <module>
    x[i]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

In [319]: x[1.2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-319-28ffb042b45f>", line 1, in <module>
    x[1.2]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

If you must iterate by index (it may not be necessary here), use `range`:

```
In [321]: for i in range(len(x)):
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     print(x[i])
     ...: 
     ...: 
0
1.2
1
3.2
2
0.5
```